# Exchange files (up to many GB)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

For my project, I have to create a file manager which aims at storing many files (from many locations) and exposing URL to download them.

In a micro-service ecosystem (I am used to use spring boot), I wonder what is the best way to exchange such files, I mean sending files to file manager?

On a one hand, I always thought it is better to exchange them asynchronously, so HTTP does not seem a good choice. But maybe I am wrong.

Is it a good choice to split files into fragments (in order to reduce number of bytes for each part) and send each of them through something like RabbitMQ or Kafka? Or should I rather transfer entire files on a NAS or through FTP and let file manager handling them? Or something else, like for example storing bytes in a temp database (maybe not a good choice)...

The problem of fragmentation is I have to implement a logic for keeping sort of each fragments which complicates processing of queues of topics.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, never send actual files through a message broker.

First, setup some object storage system, for example S3 (with AWS or locally with Ceph), then send the path to the file as a string with the producer, then have the consumer read that path, and download the file.

If you want to collect files off of NAS or FTP, then Apache NiFi is one tool that has connectors to systems like that.

Comment: This is what the RabbitMQ engineering team recommends. Send files using something that is designed to send files, and use your message broker to send URIs to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my professional experience working with distributed systems (JMS based), to transfer huge content between participants:

- a fragment approach should be used for request - reply model + control signals (has next, fragment counter)
- delta approach for updates.

To avoid corrupt data, a hash function result can also be transmitted and checked in both scenarios.

But as mentioned in this [e-mail thread](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-March/018724.html), a better approach is to use FTP for this kind of scenarios:

> RabbitMQ should actually not be used for big file transfers or only
>   with great care and fragmenting the files into smaller separate
>   messages.
>
> When running a single broker instance, you'd still be safe, but in a
>   clustered setup, very big messages will break the cluster.
>   Clustered nodes are connected via 1 tcp connection, which must also
>   transport a (erlang) heartbeat. If your big message takes more time to
>   transfer between nodes than the heartbeat timeout (anywhere between
>   ~20-45 seconds if I'm correct), the cluster will break and your
>   message is lost.
>   The preferred architecture for file transfer over amqp is to just send
>   a message with a link to a downloadable resource and let the file
>   transfer be handle by specialized protocol like ftp :-)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is an interesting answer. But I wonder how it can works in a micro-service ecosystem. In particular when file manager service runs with docker. The container should be agnostic from physical  server on which it runs. So I don't know how I can use FTP in this way. However, it open door for a solution with sharing volumes...